# Is there any way to prioritize Async calls in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node-red, loopback, event-loop

I am trying to make I/O (db) calls on input event of a Node-Red Node. So, If I have many input events, all the calls to db are added to callback queue and are processed only after nothing is left on call stack.
 This is adding up to memory and I am getting heap out of memory after some 50K input events and  because I need response from I/O to be sent to next node, the process is stopped there. 
 Is there any way I can prioritize processes from callback queue so that it is not piled up ?

Code :

```
    node.on('input', function (msg) {

        console.log("before create");

            app.models.ModelName.create(msg.payload, function (err, response) {
                            if(err){
                               return  node.error(err);
                            }
                            console.log("after create")

                            ///Process the response before sending
                                    msg.payload.msg_num = response.msg_num;

                                    node.send(msg);

                            })

            });
```

Output:
before create
before create
before create
before create
before create
before create
.
.
.
(N number of times)
after create
after create
after create
after create
after create
after create
after create
.
.
.
(N times)

Is there any way I can get the create() actually execute before all the input events are executed ?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; No

There is no callback queue, it's all one event queue and tasks are processed in order. The problem here is that the database is taking longer to reply than it takes to inject all the input data so all the inputs arrive and blow the memory before the database can process enough to free up enough memory.

The only way you can fix this is to introduce some back pressure into what ever is injecting the messages. e.g. if it's a HTTP-in/HTTP-out pair only allow a certain number of inflight sessions.

Comment: I also was suspecting the same. But, database connections are not increasing at all till the whole processing is done. Only after all before create statements are printed, the connections start increasing. I think control is not reaching to db till all processing is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case, you can use.

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

using the callback function to finish the process.

Comment: I don't have an Array ti iterate upon and do each. If I store the messages received in an Array and the do async/each, it will cause the same effect as  the array will fill up the memory.